# How to prevent duplicate function call between keyup.enter and login button onclick?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

In the following form, when the focus is moved to login button using keyboard and hitting enter executes the process() function twice.  How to make the form to call process() function only once in all of the following instances?

1) User presses (using keyboard) enter to submit button (irrespective of the focus on login button)
2) User clicks on login button (using mouse)

```
<form (keyup.enter)=process()>
    Email: <input name="email">
    Password: <input name="password">
    <button type="submit" (click)=process()>Login</button>
</form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

Place inside your `process` function [e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), this will stop the propagation of events.

```
process(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 /* YOUR LOGIC */
}
```

Aso look at this : [e.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: I tried both preventDefault and stopPropagation, but still process function is executed twice upon hitting enter key. 


Trial1:
Template: process($event)
TS: process(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
}

Trial 2:
Template: process($event)
TS: process(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

Trial3:
Template: process($event); $event.stopPropagation()

Trial4: 
Template: process($event); $event.preventDefault()

Comment: `(click)="e=>process(e)"` fails with template parse errors.